# An improper integral with Fourier series

Tags: improper-integrals

I wanna evaluate this integral 
$$I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\exp(\cos(x))\sin(\sin(x))\over x}dx$$ 
so i wrote $g(x)=\exp(\cos(x))\sin(\sin(x))$ as a Fourier series 
and I found out that 
$$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} {\sin(nx)\over n!}$$
and then dividing by $x$ we have 
$$\frac{g(x)}{x} = \sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} {\sin(nx)\over xn!}$$
and the integrating from $0$ to infinity we have 
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\exp(\cos(x))\sin(\sin(x))\over x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} {\sin(nx)\over xn!}=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(nx)\over xn!}$$ because of the uniform convergence of the series then we found out that that integral is equal to
$$\frac{\pi\exp(1)}{2}$$ 
while when I look in this integral in wolframalpha I found out that this integral from 0 to 200  is 2.69...which does not equal the previous result so what is the problem=

Comment: The $n=0$ term is zero, so the answer should be $\frac{\pi (e-1)}{2}$

Comment: The numerator is the imaginary part of $\exp(e^{ix})$.

Comment: thank you conrad